Move specific column information to a new row under the current row
Consider this df:
data = { 'Name Type': ["Primary", "Primary", "Primary"],
         'Full Name': ["John Snow", "Daenerys Targaryen", "Brienne Tarth"], 
         'AKA': ["Aegon Targaryen", None, None],
         'LQAKA': ["The Bastard of Winterfell", "Mother of Dragons", None],
         'Other': ["Info", "Info", "Info"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I need to move akas and lqakas if they are not None below each Primary name and also assign the Name Type to be AKA or LQAKA. If it is None, no row should be created. There are many other columns like column other that should keep info in the same row as Primary name. So the expected result would be:



Name Type
Full Name
Other




Primary
John Snow
Info


AKA
Aegon Targaryen



LQAKA
The Bastard of Winterfell



Primary
Daenerys Targaryen
Info


LQAKA
Mother of Dragons



Primary
Brienne Tarth
Info




You can melt+dropna+sort_index and post-process:
# reshape, remove None, and reorder
out = (df.melt(['Name Type', 'Other'], ignore_index=False)
         .dropna(subset='value')
         .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
         .rename(columns={'value': 'Full Name'})
       )

# identify rows with "Full Name"
m = out['variable'].ne('Full Name')
# mask unwanted entries
out.loc[m, 'Name Type'] = out.pop('variable')
out.loc[m, 'Other'] = ''

Variant with stack, that will directly reshape in the desired order and drop the None automatically:
out = df.set_index(['Name Type', 'Other']).stack().reset_index(name='Full Name')

m = out['level_2'].ne('Full Name')
out.loc[m, 'Name Type'] = out.pop('level_2')
out.loc[m, 'Other'] = ''

Output:
  Name Type Other                  Full Name
0   Primary  Info                  John Snow
1       AKA                  Aegon Targaryen
2     LQAKA        The Bastard of Winterfell
3   Primary  Info         Daenerys Targaryen
4     LQAKA                Mother of Dragons
5   Primary  Info              Brienne Tarth

handling many columns
Assuming you can identify the 3 columns to melt, you could modify the above approach to:
cols = df.columns.difference(['Full Name', 'AKA', 'LQAKA'])

out = (df.melt(cols, ignore_index=False)
         .dropna(subset='value')
         .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
         .rename(columns={'value': 'Full Name'})
       )
m = out['variable'].ne('Full Name')
out.loc[m, 'Name Type'] = out.pop('variable')
out.loc[m, cols[1:]] = ''
out = out[['Name Type', 'Full Name']+list(cols[1:])]

Output:
  Name Type                  Full Name Other Other2 Other3
0   Primary                  John Snow  Info  info2  info3
1       AKA            Aegon Targaryen                    
2     LQAKA  The Bastard of Winterfell                    
3   Primary         Daenerys Targaryen  Info  info2  info3
4     LQAKA          Mother of Dragons                    
5   Primary              Brienne Tarth  Info  info2  info3

exploding lists if any in the input
Adding an explode step:
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name Type': ["Primary", "Primary", "Primary"],
        'Full Name': ["John Snow", "Daenerys Targaryen", "Brienne Tarth"], 
        'AKA': [["Aegon Targaryen", "Lord Snow"], None, None],
        'LQAKA': ["The Bastard of Winterfell", ["Mother of Dragons", "The Unburnt"], 
        None],
        'Other': ["Info", "Info", "Info"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

cols = df.columns.difference(['Full Name', 'AKA', 'LQAKA'])

out = (df.melt(cols, ignore_index=False)
         .dropna(subset='value')
         .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
         .rename(columns={'value': 'Full Name'})
         .explode('Full Name', ignore_index=True)
       )
m = out['variable'].ne('Full Name')
out.loc[m, 'Name Type'] = out.pop('variable')
out.loc[m, cols[1:]] = ''
out = out[['Name Type', 'Full Name']+list(cols[1:])]

Output:
  Name Type                  Full Name Other
0   Primary                  John Snow  Info
1       AKA            Aegon Targaryen      
2       AKA                  Lord Snow      
3     LQAKA  The Bastard of Winterfell      
4   Primary         Daenerys Targaryen  Info
5     LQAKA          Mother of Dragons      
6     LQAKA                The Unburnt      
7   Primary              Brienne Tarth  Info


Hi @mozway, it looks good, the only issue is that I have like 70 additional columns like the column Other.

@Nazar then add them in the list in melt. You can generate this list programatically (from the position or by difference with the 3 columns to melt if needed, in this case you have to provide a bit more info, but it's easy to modify)

the "handling many columns" option works perfectly on a sample but not on real data. For some reason for melt part I get:
ValueError: Per-column arrays must each be 1-dimensional
I guess it will be hard to understand what's going on without seeing the data, and I can't share it(. Nevertheless, thanks a lot @mozway

@Nazar most likely your columns are not named exactly ['Full Name', 'AKA', 'LQAKA']. Make sure to use the exact names in cols = df.columns.difference(['Full Name', 'AKA', 'LQAKA']). Can you try to create a minimal dummy example that reproduces the issue? Do you still have the issue when testing on df = df.iloc[:1]

thanks @mozway yeah had duplicate column names

@Nazar thanks for the feedback. Btw, I saw you just deleted a new question, still interested in an answer?

yes I will post later, needed to change the description @mozway

hi @mozway could you add the version if instead of a single string, the AKA and LQAKA contain a list of strings?
